# Swift: How to build a grid in swift ui

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui

I want to create a grid of three colums that is sourced through a dictionary.
so a

```
dataDict = {"a":"apple", "b":"bat", "c":"chango", "d":"december", "e":"elephant"}
```

Should produce a grid displaying the value of each item?

I tried to do with an array and it worked but I don't know how to keep the grid to 3 items

```swift
struct logo : View {

    @State private var currentstorename: String = ""
    let storeLogo = ["a","b","c", "d", "e" ]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(storeLogo, id: \.self) { button in
                    Text(button) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to do it the array about but how could this be done with dictionary and just keeping the colum to 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

[image: screenshot]

For **Xcode 11, iOS 13**:

```swift
fileprivate let dataDict = [
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "bat",
    "c": "chango",
    "d": "december",
    "e": "elephant"
]

struct Logo: View {
    @State private var currentStoreName: String = ""
    
    private let storeLogo = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    /// number of columns in grid
    private let columns = 3
    
    var body: some View {
        makeGrid()
    }
    
    private func makeGrid() -> some View {
        let count = storeLogo.count
        let rows = count / columns + (count % columns == 0 ? 0 : 1)
        
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                    ForEach(0..<self.columns) { column -> AnyView in
                        let index = row * self.columns + column
                        if index < count {
                            let logoKey = self.storeLogo[index]
                            let logo = dataDict[logoKey]
                            return AnyView(Text(logo ?? "not found"))
                        } else {
                            return AnyView(EmptyView())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

For **Xcode 12 beta, iOS 14**:

The newly introduced `LazyVGrid` or `LazyHGrid` makes it easier and cleaner to do:

```swift
struct Logo: View {
    @State private var currentStoreName: String = ""
    
    private let storeLogo = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    /// number of columns in grid
    private let columns = Array(
        repeating: GridItem(.fixed(20), spacing: 5, alignment: .center),
        count: 3
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 5, content: {
                ForEach(storeLogo, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0).foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```